# Unable to fetch received-by of a message via Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363492/can-i-fetch-only-spam-mails-via-microsoft-graph-api), I'm trying to fetch messages from a particular folder like Deleted Items.

I am following this document to achieve the above scenario: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/deleteditems/messages
```

Using the above query, I'm getting all deleted messages with a lot of information(html code) that I don't want.

I want to customize the response by retrieving only particular attributes like subject, importance, sender, sentDateTime, receiver, receivedDateTime.

I tried to query something like below using $select:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/deleteditems/messages?$select= subject, importance, sender, sentDateTime, receiver, receivedDateTime.
```

But I'm getting `400:BadRequest` error like below:

```
{
"error": {
  "code": "RequestBroker--ParseUri",
  "message": "Could not find a property named 'receiver' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'.",
  "request_id": "54f9adf-7435-5r8c-a3g6-48gx6343ac",
  "date": "2022-05-24T07:35:06"
  }
}
```

How to include receiver details along with sender details???

Comment: As the error message says, 'receiver' property does not exist. Please try querying the same by removing 'receiver' and check the result.

Comment: Tqs, by removing 'receiver' I got the result but is there no way to include receiver details too???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error.***
[image]

As I already mentioned in the comment, there is **no** such attribute named **'receiver'**. To resolve the error, try removing that **receiver** in the query and check the response.

***If you want to include receiver details along with sender details, you can try including **`toRecipients`** that gives info about receiver like below as an alternative:***

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/deleteditems/messages?$select=subject,importance,sender,sentDateTime,receivedDateTime,toRecipients
```

**Response:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
As @Dmitry Streblechenko mentioned, this only works when you are the only receiver of those messages. If there are multiple recipients, take a while to know MAPI properties and OutlookSpy as he suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response in detail. This satisfies my requirement :)

Comment: This will not work if the receiver was BCC'ed.

Comment: Or if there are multiple recipients, even if the receiver is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no receiver property. Since the message comes from a mailbox that you explicitly connect to, wouldn't receiver be the mailbox owner? Unless the message was dragged from another mailbox in Outlook.

Note that you can always request any MAPI property in your Graph query. In your particular case, you probably want `PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME` / `PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS` / `PidTagReceivedRepresentingSmtpAddress` MAPI properties. To retrieve `PidTagReceivedRepresentingSmtpAddress` property, use

```
?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x5D08')
```

You can see available MAPI properties as well as construct a Graph query that requests them in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button to see all available MAPI propetrties of a selected message or click Message (Graph) | Query Parameters | Expand.

Comment: I agree that the receiver is the mailbox owner but I want to display those details too in the response. Other than that I'm facing difficulty understanding your answer. Instead, I have to explore what MAPI property is which added an extra task for me:(

Comment: Graph does not expose all properties available on a message and visible in Outlook. Do look at available MAPI properties in OutlookSpy - these properties can be requested from Graph anyway using `expand` / `singleValueExtendedProperties`. Start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http